# Not in table between dates

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

terminal

```
id   text
1    abc
2    def
3    dfg
```

termusage

```
id  termid   date
1   1        2010-11-01
2   1        2010-10-13
3   2        2010-11-10
4   3        2010-11-13
```

+ many more records (10 million) approv half are within the date (2010-11-01 and 2010-12-01)

What i want to do is find the terminal.id of the records that do not exist in the termusage table between 2010-11-01 and 2010-12-01

I have looked at select where not exists but nothing is being returned - example

```
select * from terminal
where not exists (
select * from termusage where date between '2010-11-01' and '2010-12-01' group by termid)
```

Can anyone please explain how i need to use the where not exists clause or another method !! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using `exists` is a faster solution:

```
select * from terminal t
where not exists (
    select * from termusage tu 
    where (t.id = tu.termid) and (date between '2010-11-01' and '2010-12-01')
)
```

Comment: No, dependent subqueries are _never_ a faster solution.

Comment: @Tomalak Nope. It depends no many many factors. By the way keep in mind how `exists` work.

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN` on your query and you'll see the dependant subquery.

Comment: This actually runs a LOT LOT faster than the suggestion from @Tomalak

Comment: @Tomalak I mean that dependent subquery is not always an evil. Dependent subqueries can be slower or faster depending on situation. Also, if `exists` clause finds the needed row then it stops finding process. So in this case is just my guess about the performance. I can be right or wrong. The question's author has to test it because I don't know much about his data.

Comment: There are 450000 entries in the terminals table and 28 million (i originally thought it had just 10 million) entries in the termusage table .... this query runs within 5 seconds and gives me the correct result

Comment: @ManseUK: I'd be interested in seeing `EXPLAIN` output for each respective query, for future reference. Please post both on codepad and provide an URL, if you get a chance.

Comment: @Tomalak Most likely you haven't got a notification from ManseUK.

Comment: @ManseUK: Thanks. That `WHERE` and `DISTINCT` on a derived table doesn't look too friendly.

Comment: @Tomalak - something I can fix ? I am still trying to work out the results of the explain command - im starting to think only Yoda could understand it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from terminal
    where id not in (
        select termid from usage where date between '2010-11-01' and '2010-12-01')
```

Comment: Though it's nice and concise, in the real world this is not practical. Avoid dependent subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id FROM usage u 
    INNER JOIN terminal t ON t.id = u.termid AND u.date NOT BETWEEN '2010-11-01' and '2010-12-01'
```

Comment: Will this give me terminals that are not present within the termusage table ?

Comment: @ManseUK: If you're talking about JJ's, yes it will be if you have lots of data. You should avoid dependent subqueries like that.

Comment: (It also sounds like you haven't looked at [range optimisations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html) at all!)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `terminal`.`id`
  FROM `terminal`
  LEFT JOIN
      (
       SELECT `termid`
         FROM `termusage`
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2010-12-01"
      )
    AS `_` ON (`terminal`.`id` = `_`.`termid`)
 WHERE ISNULL(`_`.`termid`)
```

The `ON` clause indicates how the `LEFT JOIN` will be performed, and the `_` is a table alias. A table alias is required here.

BTW, what's `termusage`.`id` for? Do you really need that column?

Comment: This ran in seconds - thank you .... can you please explain the USING clause ? and the '_'

Comment: @ManseUK: I've finished now. :) I have tested this last version with all sorts of data, using the schema you described.

Comment: Sorry, one final edit. I thought you wanted IDs that _are_ found in `termusage`.

Comment: OK - running your latest edit .... thanks for your time and help ... appreciated...

Comment: The Left join select - this is going to return 5 million rows of date - can i not add a group by or DISTINCT on this select to return just the unique entries ?

Comment: And having the dates enclosed in double quotes is making them strings .... perhaps its just StackOverflow issue ?

Comment: @ManseUK: No, you can't. You have to pass _all_ the results per id to the outer query, otherwise the outer query cannot see that _none_ of those are matching. With range optimisations, though, this should still be fast... do you not have an index on `date`?

Comment: @ManseUK: If not via strings, how else do you usually input dates into queries?

Comment: If i specify the dates using single quotes then the EXPLAIN results show the index of the date column being used - using double quotes doesnt .... i understand the date needs to be a string - but the difference between single and double quotes seems to be having a big consequence ...

Comment: @ManseUK: I can neither explain nor replicate that. "[Date and time values can be represented as quoted strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-values.html)", and "[A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“'”) or double quote (“"”) characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html)".

Comment: Maybe its MySQL Workbench that is screwing up the quotes ?!?